# UFT executes application in multiple instances

Tags: automated-tests, desktop-application, hp-uft

I have an `UFT` testcase to test a desktop application. I set application to be executed during test execution under `Record and Run settings` in `UFT`. Application is executed, but twice in each test execution.

Comment: Please show the code you have causing the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following suggestions:

1. Check the run iterations settings
2. Use a for loop to iterate through the rows in datatable.

Count the number of rows and set the counter for each row.

```
rowcount = DataTable.GetSheet("Global").GetRowCount
DataTable. SetCurrentRow(2)
```

Comment: I don't use `DataTable` in this test.

Comment: So you can proove that your Global DataTable is empty (DataTable.GlobalSheet.GetRowCount should return zero) and the the File->Settings->Run is not on execute test for each row in data table.

IN case both answer are positive then please share something more from your code

Comment: @BelaTamasJozsa : Element looks like this: `UIAWindow("MyApplication").UIAWindow("JavaFX173").UIAEdit("JavaFX174").SetValue "mypassword"` It appears in a new window inside application.

Comment: you mean this is the full content of your Action1? You original question is related to multiple executions / iterations and not Object Recognitions